# Manipulate button properties from a template in a JS node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom

I have an HTML template consisting of a DIV that contains three buttons.

```
<template ID="template3buttons">
    <div ID="container3buttons" class="boxes">
        <div ID= "sunShadeUp" class="boxes">
            <input type="button" 
               id="SunshadeButtonUp" 
               class="SunshadeSmallButton"
               onclick="GenericAction('ENO_ShutterStop($all)', 'all')" 
               value=""/>
        </div>
        <div ID= "sunShadeStop" class="boxes">
            <input type="button" 
               id="SunshadeButtonStop"
               class="SunshadeSmallButton"
               onclick="GenericAction('ENO_ShutterStop($all)', 'all')" 
               value=""/>
        </div>
        <div ID= "sunShadeDown" class="boxes">
            <input type="button" 
               id="SunshadeButtonDown"
               class="SunshadeSmallButton"
               onclick="GenericAction('ENO_ShutterStop($all)', 'all')" 
               value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I use JS to generate many copies of the template, which are eventually inserted into appropriate DIVs.

```
function create3Button(cellButtonId) //create boxes with 3 buttons each
{
    var template3buttons = document.querySelector('#template3buttons');
    var insertionPoint= document.getElementById(cellButtonId);
    var clone = document.importNode(template3buttons.content, true);
    insertionPoint.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Now, i need to manipulate the content of the 'onclick' tag for each copy of the template depending on the insertion point. I understand that `getElementById()` does not work for DOM nodes. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery you can do this:

```
$("[id*=sunShade]").children().click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: Dear lkmac, thank you for your kind help. Your suggestion works fine if I do 
    '$("#box11").children().click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
where box11 is one of 20 boxes containing the replicas of the template. I was wondering, however, if there is a more elegant way of extracting the number "11" from the Id of the DIV and use that programmatically, so that I would not have to maintain 20 consecutive buttons.

Comment: Sorry didn't get your answer originally. I updated my answer, try now.